# access to new dynamically controls in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, controls

First of all excuse me for my poor grammar and vocabulary :)

please see this source and run it:

```
Public Class Form1
Public pointX As Integer
Public pointY As Integer = 32
Public dynamicText As TextBox
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pointX = 330
    For i = 1 To 4
        dynamicText = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
        dynamicText.Name = "T" + Trim(Str(i))
        dynamicText.Text = ""
        dynamicText.Location = New Point(pointX, pointY)
        dynamicText.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        Me.Controls.Add(dynamicText)
        pointX = pointX - 106
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    pointX = 330
    pointY = pointY + 26
    For i = 1 To 4
        dynamicText = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
        dynamicText.Name = "T" + Trim(Str(i))
        dynamicText.Text = ""
        dynamicText.Location = New Point(pointX, pointY)
        dynamicText.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        Me.Controls.Add(dynamicText)
        pointX = pointX - 106

        AddHandler dynamicText.Click, AddressOf printHello1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub printHello1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox(dynamicText.Name)
    If dynamicText.Name = "T1" Then MsgBox("Oh! this is T1")
End Sub
End Class
```

**why If never is not true?!
why MsgBox(dynamicText.Name) always return T4?!
i want all controlls to be access by name or array of names.**
please help me thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The global variable `dynamicText` takes the value of the last TextBox added in the loop inside the Button1_Click event. This happens to be the control named `T4`. You don't really need a global variable in this case. You can cast the sender parameter to a TextBox instance because the sender parameter is the control that has raised the event.

```
Private Sub printHello1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim txt = CType(sender, "TextBox")
    if txt IsNot Nothing then
        MsgBox(txt.Name)
        If txt.Name = "T1" Then MsgBox("Oh! this is T1")
    End If
End Sub
```

You also don't need to recreate the controls again in the button click event. The action executed in the form load event is enough (You could add the AddHandler there). Global variables are dangerous, avoid them when possible.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is acceptable. Place a panel at the bottom of your form, set Dock to Bottom, add a single button to the panel and a TextBox. Place a FlowLayoutPanel onto the form, Dock = Fill, AutoScroll = True.

The code below creates the amount of TextBox controls as inputted into TextBox. Each newly created TextBox a click event is added with simple logic.

Form code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, count) Then
            Dim demo = New TextBoxCreate(FlowLayoutPanel1, "Demos", count)
            demo.CreateTextBoxes()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Class code (add a new class to the project, name it TextBoxCreate.vb)

```
Public Class TextBoxCreate
    Public Property TextBoxes As TextBox()
    Public Property TextBoxBaseName As String
    Public Property TextBoxCount As Integer
    Public Property ParentControl As Control

    Public Sub New(
        ByVal ParentControl As Control,
        ByVal BaseName As String,
        ByVal Count As Integer)

        Me.ParentControl = ParentControl
        Me.TextBoxBaseName = BaseName
        Me.TextBoxCount = Count
    End Sub
    Public Sub CreateTextBoxes()
        Dim Base As Integer = 10
        TextBoxes = Enumerable.Range(0, TextBoxCount).Select(
            Function(Indexer)

                Dim b As New TextBox With
                    {
                        .Name = String.Concat(TextBoxBaseName, Indexer + 1),
                        .Text = (Indexer + 1).ToString,
                        .Width = 150,
                        .Location = New Point(25, Base),
                        .Parent = Me.ParentControl,
                        .Visible = True
                    }

                AddHandler b.Click, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
                                        If tb.Name = TextBoxBaseName & "1" Then
                                            tb.Text = "Got it"
                                        Else
                                            MessageBox.Show(tb.Name)
                                        End If

                                    End Sub
                Me.ParentControl.Controls.Add(b)

                Base += 30

                Return b

            End Function).ToArray
    End Sub
End Class
```